# Where is the edit panel for SCA tree generator?

Tags: edit-mode

After adding tree to scene there is no editing panel. Where can i find this?
[image]

It usually showed up in the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should hit that little plus button at the bottom. Or use F6.